# Self modifying code vs compiler optimizations vs duplicate code

Tags: c++

I became a bit stressed as I cannot make my C++ code efficient without compromise. I came into writing some code which goes like the following

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int result;
    bool cond1 = bar1(a, b, c);
    bool cond2 = bar2(a, b, c);
    bool cond3 = bar3(a, b, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 10000;
        if (cond1)
            start = max(start, baz1(i));
        else
            start = max(start, baz2(i));
        if (cond2)
            end = min(end, baz1(i));
        else
            end = min(end, baz2(i));
        for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
        {
            if (cond3)
                result += baz3(i, j);
            else
                result -= baz3(i, j);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The question is, how to optimize it to not check the conditions "cond1, cond2, cond3" in every iteration of the loops. I could write the inner loops as

```
...
        if (cond3)
        for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
            result += baz3(i, j);
        else
        for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
            result -= baz3(i, j);

...
```

which reduced the number of checks of "cond3" from 10000 times something down to just 10000 checks. However there are still 29997 redundant checks, and in order to optimize it I only see the option to duplicate the loop 2^3 = 8 times. Because of this exponential growth in #loops vs #conditions I have some questions:

1. Can I rely on the compiler optimizer to unroll the loops?
2. What are the arguments against self-modifying code, as not only would the program size be decreased in this case, but the code also be more manageable. I find it hard to believe that a problem such as the above has not been encountered since the time C++ was invented.

Comment: Did you take a look at any compiler's output code?

Comment: The arguments against self-modifying code were pretty well laid down probably 40 years ago -- it makes code buggy and inefficient.

Comment: If the compiler can ascertain that `cond1`, `cond2` and `cond3` are unchanged in the loop's body, it will likely optimize the crap out of it at high optimization levels. But the code as-is is poorly designed. Do you need performance, portability, or maintainability? Pick any two.

Comment: You have at most 8 variations.  If you're so worried about performance you can code 8 separate versions of the entire routine and select which to execute.  In a way that would be less obscure than all the if tests.

Comment: No I did not take a look at the compiler's output code. I have read that level -O3 unrolls loops, but I am in doubt since there is an exponential number of versions in e.g. this example. How can the code become buggy and inefficient? I only see more maintainable and small-sized code, and coding 8 different versions of the routine I would do if necessary. As for the performance, portability and maintainability, isn't or is Java supposed to be able to draw efficiencies like these at run-time?

Comment: @user2275809 Loop unrolling will be done for small number iterations as these are seen at compile time. Unrolling a big number of iterations will surely not be considered an optimization, would it? Think about CPU cache hits, etc.

Comment: Addition to @HotLicks comment: Using [tag:c++] lambda functions could be used to make such technique even more localized and readable.

Comment: Try actually doing code modification sometime.  You'll find out what "buggy and inefficient" means.

Comment: also, you arent compromising between self modifying or not, you are compromising between minimal speed changes and small readability changes and modest maintainability changes (the 8 separate loops idea is kind of bad from a maintenance perspective)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destress.

Do some benchmarks, but my prediction is that your code is just fine because it  is optimal for even the simplest form of branch prediction which will make all of those tests almost free, and certainly cheaper than a function call, never mind an indirect function call.

If baz1 and baz2 are trivial, make sure they can be inlined. If they are not trivial, an almost always successfully predicted branch is inconsequential.

Answer (score 3):

Function Pointers.  Use function pointers.
Use 3 function pointers, one for each condition.

For example:

```
  Function_Pointer_Type_Cond1 p_cond_1_function;
  Function_Pointer_Type_Cond2 p_cond_2_function;
  if (bar1(a, b, c))
  {
    p_cond_1_function = baz1;
  }
  else
  {
    p_cond_1_function = baz2;
  }
  if (bar2(a, b, c))
  {
    p_cond_2_function = baz1;
  }
  else
  {
    p_cond_2_function = baz2;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    int start = 0;
    int end = 10000;
    start = max(start, (*p_cond_1_function)(i));
    end   = min(end,   (*p_cond_2_function)(i));
    // ...
  }
```

Using function pointers can remove the "if" statements.  You would assign the function pointer before the loop, since the functions don't change within the `for` loop.

For more information about function pointers, search the web for "C++ FAQ function pointer" or search StackOverflow for "C++ function pointer".

Comment: Hmm perhaps I did not tell, the "baz" functions might as well be inline, they are three arithmetic operations so a full calling procedure would be more inefficient than the "if" checks.

Comment: @user2275809 Without measuring it's hard to categorically state that a function call is more expensive than testing and branching.

Comment: @user2275809 Wouldn't lambdas effectively be locally inlined functions (if the compiler decides they're eligible as such)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove the third `if`.

Just always do addition inside the loop, and negate the result after the loop , before returning, if cond3 so indicates.